# how to set li active class using php if clicked

Tags: php

Hello I would like to set `li` active in PHP: if it's clickable, then it's active, if not then it's not active. I've tried several ways but nothing works. Here's my code :

```
<ul>
<?php

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE isRoot='1' ORDER BY pageID");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
    {

        echo "<li><a href=\"".DIR.rawurlencode ($row->pageTitle)."\">$row->pageTitle</a>    </li>"; 
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Avoid `mysql`. Use `PDO` or `mysqli`

Comment: What do you mean with *"if it's clickable"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to us a GET parameter.

The link to your site than will be index.php?pageID=11 - in this case 11 stands for die pageID 11

in your while loop you have to check if this site is the active one

```
if($row->pageID == $_GET['pageID'])
{
   //active li
   echo "<li class="active"><a href=\"".DIR.rawurlencode ($row->pageTitle)."\">$row->pageTitle</a>    </li>";
}
else
{
   //normal li
   echo "<li><a href=\"".DIR.rawurlencode ($row->pageTitle)."\">$row->pageTitle</a>    </li>";
}
```

You could do the same with PageTitle too